# Is Windows Authentication enough to sign my user in?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, authorization, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application using Identity. It is an intranet application and I am requiring all users be authenticated using Windows Authentication, which uses Kerberos.

I want to have the system be seamless for the user, so that when they access the page and they are not signed in but are authenticated, they are automatically signed in using their `User.Identity.Name` which corresponds to their Identiy Username which I first check to see if exists with `UserManager.FindByIdAsync`

If it does exist, I sign them in using the `SignInManager`. If it doesn't exist, I create a new user in the Identity store and then sign that user in.

Is this assuming too much? is this potentially going to come back and bite me, or is this perfectly acceptable? Most examples I see exist with user credentials being transmitted to sign the user in to Active Directory.

Answer (score 1):

With integrated authentication IIS becomes the point at which users login, and you don't need, and shouldn't use Identity 3.0 - you don't need it, AD is the user database here, you don't need to add Identity.

When you create a new application you should click the change authentication button in the new project dialog and choose Windows authentication. That will configure everything correctly and won't add any of the Identity pieces.

Note that in RC1 [authorization based on role/AD group membership](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/roles.html) is broken, so `Authorize[Roles = "MYDOMAIN\mygroup"]` won't work. This will be fixed in RC2.

Comment: Windows Forms Authentication was a typo. My apologies. I don't know where Forms even came from as I'm using a strict Web API/SPA setup. I'm mostly using Identity as a means to attach additional information to the users that pertain specifically to my application... stuff that Active Directory should not be concerned with. That is a valid use of Identity above and beyond what Integrated Authentication provides, isn't it? Preferences, additional roles that extend beyond the logic of our AD, etc.